# How to get product Review and Rating information by using Magento APIs

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento API for getting product information from other server i.e.

```
$soap = new SoapClient('http://example.com/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $soap->login('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx');
$productInfo = $soap->call($sessionId, 'product.info','123');
```

The above code is ok for me for getting product information, but I have to collect product reviews and rating information for the particular product and I am not getting such a method in Magento APIs list http://www.magentocommerce.com/support/magento_core_api  to get it.

So can you help me please? How can I get product Review and Rating information i.e. id, name, text, rating and date using Magento APIs only.

Thanks.

Preeti.

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently possible using Magento's default api.  You would need to [extend the api](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api).  I took a quick look for existing extensions that extended the api to include customer reviews but didn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: I agree. To add extra api methods in magento is quite easy.